# How can I mix a column and line chart in Rails using Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I would like to present graphs in my rails app. I was able to find a lot of projects that could do that, as [Chartkick](http://chartkick.com/).
But I would like to have charts like [this one](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-and-line-mix/), where I max lines and columns. Is there any project that is able to draw this kind of graphs? I was not able to find anything on chartkick's website or Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Visualization `Combo charts` should be able to do what you are looking for

Have a look at [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) for more info

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mH3u7/1/)

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this using chartkick:

```
= column_chart(@your_data, library: { :series => { 0 => { type: "line"} } })
```

This will set the first series in @your_data as the line chart. Of course you can set every other series in that as well just exchange the "0" for another number.

I hope this helps!

Comment: maybe you can show how this would look like in javascript?

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. It seems to be contradicted by [this](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/263#issuecomment-339586412): "Chartkick doesn't currently support any type of combo chart."

Comment: It doesn't work with chartkick gem, any luck yet ? @klenwell

Comment: @klenwell that does actually work but you need to add: `adapter: 'google', library:...`

and you need: `javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in Javascript using something like:

```
new Chartkick.AreaChart("chart", [{"name":"Series 1","data":{"2013-03-11 00:00:00 -0700":3,"2013-03-31 00:00:00 -0700":5}},{"name":"Series 2","data":{"2013-02-10 00:00:00 -0800":0,"2013-02-17 00:00:00 -0800":0}},{"name":"Series 3","data":{"2013-02-10 00:00:00 -0800":0,"2013-02-17 00:00:00 -0800":1}}], { library: { series: { 0: { color: "blue" }, 1: { type: "line", color: "yellow" }, 2: { type: "line", color: "green" } } } }  );
```

Series 2 and 3 will be lined, and Series 1 will be an area chart. :)

(This is primarily a response to JNM's question on Timo's answer, but I can't reply to comments at the moment. :/ )